# MySQL netting of rows based on available stock

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL database that includes a table of orders and table of part numbers with available stock.

For example

```
==Orders Table==
part_number
order_date
qty

==Stock Table==
part_number
stock_qty
```

Assuming that available stock will be assigned to the most recent orders, how  would I select rows from the orders table that don't have stock to cover them.

The orders table could have between 1.5 and 2 million records so reading the whole data set into memory and processing in PHP first is not ideal.

===Update and Final Answer===

Gordon's answer gave me enough information to get the exact result that worked for me. which I have included below.

```
select * from (
select o.*,s.stock_qty,(@netted_stock := if(@pn = o.part_number,@netted_stock-sumqty,s.stock_qty-sumqty)) as netted_stock
from (select o.*,
             (@sumqty := if(@pt = part_number, @sumqty + qty,
                            if(@pt := part_number, qty, qty)
                           )
             ) as sumqty



      from orders o cross join
           (select @pn := -1, @sumqty := 0, @netted_stock:= 0) params
      order by part_number, order_date desc
     ) o join
     stock s
     on o.part_number = s.part_number
     ) s
```

Here is the result it gives me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cumulative sum of stock per order.  You can get that with variables.  The rest is just simple logic:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             (@sumqty := if(@pt = part_number, @sumqty + qty,
                            if(@pt := part_number, qty, qty)
                           )
             ) as sumqty
      from orders o cross join
           (select @pn := -1, @sumqty := 0) params
      order by part_number, order_date desc
     ) o join
     stock s
     on o.part_number = s.part_number
where s.stock_qty < o.sumqty;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you are on the edge of my knowledge for MySQL (but I like that). I will pick my way through your suggestion and give it a try. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The query seems to the do the opposite of what I need, I only brings back rows that have stock available. I can see what your doing though and I tried to fix but beyond my ability. I could do with the sumqty field being a netted of stock value i.e. On order = 2, current_stock = 10, sumqty = 8. Then I could select on anything where sumqty was <= 0

Comment: @PrestonDocks . . . Fixed the comparison.